# Multiple copy buffers in tmux's vi copy mode

Tags: shell, vi, tmux

Vi has named buffers by typing `"[a-z]`, followed by your yank/delete/etc command. Does tmux's vi copy-mode have named buffers? I'd like to copy various strings into different tmux buffers and be able to paste them individually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does.

`man tmux` `/^BUFFERS` or [the web copy](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#BUFFERS):

> tmux maintains a set of named paste buffers.  Each buffer may be either
>        explicitly or automatically named.  Explicitly named buffers are named
>        when created with the set-buffer or load-buffer commands, or by renam‐
>        ing an automatically named buffer with set-buffer -n.  Automatically
>        named buffers are given a name such as ‘buffer0001’, ‘buffer0002’ and
>        so on.  When the buffer-limit option is reached, the oldest automati‐
>        cally named buffer is deleted.  Explicitly named buffers are not sub‐
>        ject to buffer-limit and may be deleted with delete-buffer command.
>
> Buffers may be added using copy-mode or the set-buffer and load-buffer
>        commands, and pasted into a window using the paste-buffer command.  If
>        a buffer command is used and no buffer is specified, the most recently
>        added automatically named buffer is assumed.
>
> ...
>
> The buffer commands are as follows:
>
> ...
>
> ```
> load-buffer [-b buffer-name] path
>                (alias: loadb)
>          Load the contents of the specified paste buffer from path.
>
> paste-buffer [-dpr] [-b buffer-name] [-s separator] [-t target-pane]
>                (alias: pasteb)
>          Insert the contents of a paste buffer into the specified pane.
>          If not specified, paste into the current one.  With -d, also
>          delete the paste buffer.  When output, any linefeed (LF) char‐
>          acters in the paste buffer are replaced with a separator, by
>          default carriage return (CR).  A custom separator may be speci‐
>          fied using the -s flag.  The -r flag means to do no replacement
>          (equivalent to a separator of LF).  If -p is specified, paste
>          bracket control codes are inserted around the buffer if the
>          application has requested bracketed paste mode.
> ```

I truncated some of the information (including other buffer commands); definitely take a look at the website above (or the man page) for how to use these tools.

Comment: There are other things you can do with named buffers; for example, you can make `choose-buffer` show only a subset of buffers. Say you create a bunch of preset buffers with your favourite text and a common name prefix like `mybuffer0`, `mybuffer1` etc, you can bind a key to for example `choose-buffer -f '#{m:mybuffer*,#{buffer_name}}'` to select from only those buffers. Or just bind keys to paste them directly `pasteb -bmybuffer0`.